# Is the Athlon 64 X2 (W) 4600+ 2.4 GHz a 64-bit processor?

Tags: cpu, 64-bit, amd-athlon

I have an Athlon 64 X2 (W) 4600+ 2.4 GHz processor, with Windows XP 32-bit.
I have read that the AMD 64, is actually a backwards compatible (32/64) processor, so you can run either Windows 32-bit or 64-bit if you want.

When I go into my system information, it reads:
Processor   x86 Family 15 Model 75 Stepping 2 AuthenticAMD ~2405 MHz

It says it is a 32-bit.  So do I have a 32-bit or 64-bit processor?  And can I upgrade to Windows 7 64-bit?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, all Athlon 64 X2 processors are 64-bits.  You can upgrade to Windows 7 64-bit.

I don't know why your system information says it's a 32-bit processor.  Perhaps because you're running a 32-bit OS, it is showing you the mode that it's currently running rather than the full capabilities of the processor.

Comment: On a side note, if I upgrade to 7 64bit, will my computer recognize more of my installed memory? (4gb installed and 3.43 recognized under xp).

Comment: Yes, with windows 64bit you'll have the the full 4gb ram available. with windows 32bit it's max 4gb and the video card ram get's subtracted from this 4gb. that's why you only have 3.43gb available.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is a 64-bit processor, but you are probably running a 32-bit operating system.